# Array from SharedArrayBuffer is always filled with zeros

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, buffer

Basically, no matter what I do any array made from a buffer (doesn't have to be shared) results in an array the same length of elements as the buffer, but all of its values are zero. Note I need to do this in chrome and the Mozilla docs on typed arrays don't seem to hold for chrome.

I want an array representing a buffer that already has data in it. My use case is a webworker receiving a shared array buffer that already has data in it. However, I am not successful in creating a view that represents that buffer.

```
function testIntBuffer(n) {
    return new SharedArrayBuffer(Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * n);
}

function fillIntBuffer(buffer, endInt) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= endInt; i++) {
        buffer[i] = i;
    }
    return buffer;
}

var a = testIntBuffer(10);
fillIntBuffer(a, 10);
console.log(a);

var b = new Int32Array(a);
console.log(b)
```

This is what the real code in my project looks like (aside from the fake data function):

```
//inside main.js
function fakeDataArray(n) {
    const arr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    }
    return arr;
}

function normalArrayToSBA(rawData) {
    const n = rawData.length;
    const m = Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    const data = new SharedArrayBuffer(m * n);
    rawData.forEach((datum, i) => {
        data[i] = datum;
    });
    return [data, n, m];
}

function createWorker() {
        const w = new Worker('workerBundle.js');
        w.onmessage = (event) => {
            const command = event.data.command;
            if (command === 'workerFinish') {
                console.log('event recieved from worker: ', event);
            }
            if (!command) {
                return;
            }
        };
        return w;
    }

function startworker(dataInfo, options) {
    const worker = createWorker();
    function setWorkerData(dataInfo) {
        const priceBuffer = dataInfo[0];
        const size = dataInfo[1];
        const offset = dataInfo[2];
        worker.postMessage({
            command: 'setData',
            priceBuffer: priceBuffer,
            size: size,
            offset: offset
        });
    }
    function getWorkerStats(_options) {
        worker.postMessage({
            command: 'getStats',
            options: _options,
        });
    }
    const id = Math.random();
    setWorkerData(dataInfo);
    getWorkerStats(options);
}

let data = fakeDataArray(5751);
let dataInfo = normalArrayToSBA(data);
startworker(dataInfo);

//inside workerBundle.js

//eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const WorkerMessageInterface = {
    file: null,
    priceData: null,
    role: 'worker',
    id: null,
    pendingRequests: {},
    setRole(event) {
        WorkerMessageInterface.role = event.data.role;
        WorkerMessageInterface.id = event.data.id;
        self.postMessage({
            success: true,
            commandGiven: event.data.command
        });
    },
    //command: 'setFile'
    /*{ command: 'setFile', fileInfo: String }*/
    setFile(event) {
        WorkerMessageInterface.file = event.data.file;
        self.postMessage({
            success: true,
            commandGiven: event.data.command
        });
    },
    //command: 'setData'
    /**
     * @param {priceData} Array
     * @param {source} String - Indicates what utility mapping  is necesarry
     *                          to convert data into the highcharts format
    */
    setData(event) {
        const data = event.data;
        const priceBuffer = new Int32Array(data.priceBuffer);
        WorkerMessageInterface.priceData = [priceBuffer, data.size];
    },
    //command: 'getSignals'
    /**
     * @param {options} Object
    */
    getAverage(dataArray) {
        let sum = 0;
        let length = dataArray.length;
        dataArray.forEach((n) => {
            sum += n;
        });
        return sum / length;
    },
    getStats(event) {
        const ops = event.data.options;
        const id = WorkerMessageInterface.id;
        const data = WorkerMessageInterface.priceData;
        const stats = WorkerMessageInterface.getAverage(data);
        if (WorkerMessageInterface.role === 'worker') {
            self.postMessage({
                results: stats,
                command: 'workerFinish',
                id: id
            });
        }
    },
    listenForCommands() {
        self.onmessage = (event) => {
            const command = event.data.command;
            WorkerMessageInterface[command](event);
            self.postMessage({
                worker: true,
                commandGiven: command,
                status: 'recieved',
            });
        };
    }
};
WorkerMessageInterface.listenForCommands();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `SharedArrayBuffer` to `new Int32Array()` before calling `fillIntBuffer()`

```js
function testIntBuffer(n) {
  return new SharedArrayBuffer(Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * n);
}

function fillIntBuffer(buffer, endInt) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= endInt; i++) {
    buffer[i] = i;
  }
  return buffer;
}

var a = testIntBuffer(10);
var b = new Int32Array(a);
fillIntBuffer(b, 10);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear in my question, I want an array representing a buffer that already has data in it. My use case is a webworker receiving a shared array buffer that already has data in it. However, I am not successful in creating a view that represents that buffer.

Comment: What do you mean by "already has data in it"? The data is set within the `Int32Array` at Answer, following pattern at Question. How do you pass the `ArrayBuffer` to `Worker`? Can you include the actual code and use case description at Question?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Sure I could show you the actual code, but it convolutes the heart of the question - notice that I am first creating the buffer with a set length, filling the buffer with values, using fillIntBuffer, then attempting to construct a view on that buffer (which already has data in it) using an Int32Array. I am sending the buffer to the webworker via post message. If that still isn't clear I'll be happy to post the code itself.

Comment: An `ArrayBuffer` itself cannot be filled with values. A `TypedArray` can have values set. _"I am sending the buffer to the webworker via post message."_ Yes, though how? At which parameter? Yes, the code itself, included at the Question, would probably be helpful towards resolving inquiry.

Comment: Yes, but with the correct byte offset I should be able to construct an "array" with "elements" off of a contiguous buffer

Comment: Are you referencing an `Array` or an `ArrayBuffer`? What are you trying to achieve? What is input and expected result? Have you the read links posted at previous comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557283/array-from-sharedarraybuffer-is-always-filled-with-zeros/46557392?noredirect=1#comment80068775_46557392?

Comment: When I say buffer, I am referring to an instance of SharedArrayBuffer. When I say array I mean anything with an index/value interface. So if there's a better class/type of arrays for creating a view on top of the buffer with that I can be flexible with. 

In my specific case, the buffer has a byteLength value of  23004 with 5751 elements. I send that buffer to a webworker, which then needs to create a array from the buffer so it can iterate over those values and access them via index value.

Comment: Use the same approach at `Worker` thread. `let ab = new Int32Array(event.data); for (let i = 0; i < ab.length; i++) { // do stuff with ab[i]}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155867/discussion-between-specifically-user3827668-and-guest271314).